# Fees higher than block reward

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, mining-reward

I know this would not be possible but in-case someone just decided to try it out or accidentally put a high transaction fees (more than 12 bitcoin), so what will it happen?

Will the block reward increase or the remaining fees removed or will it not even send to the block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What happens to the fees in Bitcoin?

In Bitcoin, the transaction fees paid are *added* to the block reward so, if a miner solves a block they currently get 12.5BTC block reward *plus* the sum total of all fees. If the fees add up to 12.5BTC also then, the miner gets 25BTC in total.

Comment: so they gets the whole fees for that transaction?

Comment: @zhiyan114 Yes.